# Unity: PlayerLife variable doesn't update visibly in Inspector or HUD, but still functional in Background

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hud

The `playerLife` variable doesn't update visibly in the Inspector or the on-screen Health Text, but the `Player` still dies because the `playerLife` drops below zero.

I've determined that the `Player` prefab attached to the `Zombie` GameObject is solely the `Player` prefab rather than the in-scene active `Player`. How do I make it so that the zombies always reference the in-scene active Player rather than the basic Player prefab, by script? (Also, it won't allow me to manually drag the active Player into the Zombie)

[Call hierarchy for playerLife](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Vs8.png)

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RaycastHit hit;
    public int gunDamage = 1;
    public Zombie zombie;

    private float hitForce = 100f;
    public float playerLife;
    private Vector3 flareLower = new Vector3(0, -0.5f, 0);

    void Start()
    {
        spawnPoints = playerSpawnPoint.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
        playerLife = 200;
    }

    void Update() //T-toggle
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
        {
            LazerBeam();
        }

        if (reSpawn != lastToggle)
        {
            ReSpawn();
            reSpawn = false;
        }
        else
            lastToggle = reSpawn;
    }



    public void Life (float damage)
    {
        playerLife -= damage;
        if (playerLife <=0)
        {
            playerLife = 100;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Zombie : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int currentHealth;
    public Player player;
    public PlayerLifeCollider playerCollider; 
    private int damage;

    public void Damage(int damageAmount)
    {
        currentHealth -= damageAmount;
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            PlayerLifeCollider.instance.ObjectsInRange.Remove(gameObject);
            DestroyZombie();
        }
    }

    public void DestroyZombie()
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        // gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void DamagePlayer(float damage)
    {
         player.Life(damage);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it possible that the player dies before playerlife ever changes? If it doesn't change, it can't possibly reach zero, so the player should be invincible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't update"? Do you mean the `lifePlayer` value never changes in the Inspector until the player dies?

Comment: If I had to guess you weren't setting the player variable inside of Zombie?

Comment: It doesn't update the public variable in the Inspector but it seems to update in the background.

Comment: Ok, i figured out the problem but not sure how to fix it. I attached the Player Prefab rather then the Player GameObject and it's reducing the health of the prefab rather then the in-game Player GameObject. How do I make it so that the zombies always reference to the in-game Player GameObject?

Comment: Edited Descripton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the problem is that you are not referencing the Player object on your scene, but a prefab one. To avoid that, you can add a `Start` function to the Zombie script and ask to look for what should be the only Player instance in the scene. For this, you can use the [FindObjectOfType](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) function:

```
void Start()
{
    player = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
}
```

Considering you will only have one Player script in your entire scene, what you can also do is to save in your Player class a static reference to your Player instance.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static Player _instance;

    public static Player Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = FindObjectOfType<Player>();
            }
           return _instance;
        }
    }

    // Reset of your class

}
```

You can then get this reference in your Zombie script:

```
public class Zombie : MonoBehaviour
{
    static Player player;

    void Start()
    {
        if(player == null)
        {
            player = Player.Instance;
        }
    }

    // Rest of your class content
}
```

This way, you will only have one call to the `FindObjectOfType` function instead of once per object using the Zombie script.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Damage(int damageAmount)
{
    currentHealth -= damageAmount;

    print(currentHealth);// will show in terminal if thats what you are asking


    if (currentHealth <= 0)
    {
        PlayerLifeCollider.instance.ObjectsInRange.Remove(gameObject);
        DestroyZombie();
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the description, I've found that it's the wrong prefab attached rather than in-gameObject. Do you know how to attach in-game Object by script?

Comment: public GameObject nameOfObject;